# Cant enable GLSL 1.40 in my Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, shader

I want to porting demo project of Box2D from VS2013 in Qt. But i have one unusual problem. When i run demo project in VS i get message with info about my openGL configuration.

[image]

I replaced code on Qt and changed initialization of shaders and calls of opengl funcitons with QOpeGL wrappers.

Firstly, i change default surface format like this:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(3, 1);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

But when i debug program is format of my surface stay on 3.0.

[image]

And when i try to create shaders i get error message like this:

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): ERROR: 0:1: '140' : version number not supported
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error 
*** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
#version 140
#line 1
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
layout(location = 0) in vec2 v_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 v_color;
layout(location = 2) in float v_size;
out vec4 f_color;
void main(void)
{
    f_color = v_color;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(v_position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
gl_PointSize = v_size;
}
```

**Why VS can create shaders and work with OpenGL 3.1/GLSL 1.40, but Qt doesn't do this?**

Initialize of GL (m_functions - QOpenGLExtraFunctions)

```
void MainOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();

    qDebug() << "OPENGL " << QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat().majorVersion() <<
            "." << QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat().minorVersion();

    m_functions.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    m_functions.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    g_camera.m_width = 1024;
    g_camera.m_height = 640;

    g_debugDraw.Create(&m_functions);
}
```

function *g_debugDraw.Create(...)*:

```
void Create(QOpenGLExtraFunctions *functions)
{
    const char *vs = \
                    "#version 140\n"
                    "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;\n"
                    "layout(location = 0) in vec2 v_position;\n"
                    "layout(location = 1) in vec4 v_color;\n"
                    "layout(location = 2) in float v_size;\n"
                    "out vec4 f_color;\n"
                    "void main(void)\n"
                    "{\n"
                    "   f_color = v_color;\n"
                    "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(v_position, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
                    "   gl_PointSize = v_size;\n"
                    "}\n";

    ...

    m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vs);

    ...

    m_functions = *functions;

    m_functions.glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vaoId);
    m_functions.glGenBuffers(3, m_vboIds);

    m_functions.glBindVertexArray(m_vaoId);
    m_functions.glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_vertexAttribute);
    m_functions.glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_colorAttribute);
    m_functions.glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_sizeAttribute);

    ...
}
```

I get error when call `m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vs);`

Comment: Easy solution: don't use Qt for OpenGL. You say that your code was already written without Qt, then why port it?

Comment: @ybungalobill it's not impossible for me :) i have a half-complete desktop application and this just new feature for this app. I cant rewrite this app... if i dont solve this problem i will being use my box2d port on Qpainter. But i dont want use this port cause Opengl work faster then Qpainter.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to stick to GLSL #version 140, then replace the following lines

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 v_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 v_color;
layout(location = 2) in float v_size;
```

by

```
in vec2 v_position;
in vec4 v_color;
in float v_size;
```

Explicit attribute location is not part of GLSL until #version 330.

Be careful after that to query your shader's attribute location before enabling it in your C++ code. The shader compiler may or may not order them in the order of declaration.

```
const int POS_LOCATION = glGetAttribLocation(program_id, "v_position");
if(-1 != POS_LOCATION)
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(POS_LOCATION);
    ...
    glVertexAttribPointer(POS_LOCATION, ... );
    ...
}
```

I've found no mention of layout(location = x) in documentation of GLSL #version 140.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.40.pdf

Not mentioned until #version 330 at page 35.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf

In your case the shader compiler error message is a little misleading. Maybe if you update you graphic card driver you'll get a better shader compiler.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me sort out a little, but the problem was a bit different. I post solve later.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't took into account that GLSL for desktop is not the same that GLSL from OpenGL ES. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783173/difference-between-opengl-sl-and-opengl-es-2-0-sl) little helped me. I change all `in` to `attribute` or `varying` and all `out` to `varying` and also set precision on float. After change my shader was compile. Finally my shader code looks like this:

```
precision lowp float;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
attribute vec2 v_position;
attribute vec4 v_color;
attribute float v_size;
varying vec4 f_color;

void main(void)
{
    f_color = v_color;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(v_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = v_size;
}
```

Thank Octo for support!